# I cannot print my json object to screen with index

Tags: python

I have a code like below. Firstly, I create dict_tmp more than a time and I append it to original dict. Finally I dump the original dict to a json object. I can print the json to screen and I see the result is properly. But the problem is I cannot print the json with index.

My code:

```
def function(agents):
    for i in range(0,len(agents)):
        dict_agent_tmp = {
            "exec_name": agents[i]["exe_name"],
            "platform": agents[i]["platform"],
            "host_ip_addrs": agents[i]["host_ip_addrs"][0],
            "paw":agents[i]["paw"]
        }

        dict_agents.append(dict_agent_tmp)
    agents_json = json.dumps(dict_agents) 
    print(agents_json)
```

When I run the code, for print(agents_json)

```
print(agents_json)
```

The output is

```
[{"exec_name": "splunkd", "platform": "linux", "host_ip_addrs": "127.0.0.1", "paw": "aczrpe"}, {"exec_name": "splunkd", "platform": "linux", "host_ip_addrs": "127.0.0.1", "paw": "pghbjn"}]
```

However, for the print(agents_json[0])

```
print(agents_json[0])
```

The output is

```
[
```

Yeah, It is only "[". I expected the output to be like:

```
{"exec_name": "splunkd", "platform": "linux", "host_ip_addrs": "127.0.0.1", "paw": "aczrpe"}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `agents_json` is a string (the **s** in json.dump**s** is for string)

Comment: `agents_json` is a string, `[0]` gets its first character. You may want `agents_json = json.dumps(dict_agents[0])` and print that one.

Comment: @sretkaya There is no "JSON Object"  in python. JSON in python is represented using dicts and lists you only dump using `json` to write the JSON to a file or similar

Comment: Okay thank all of you. I am more clear right now.

Comment: A JSON object is a *string* like `'{"foo": 5}'`. Different languages *decode* JSON objects to their own native data structures: Python to a `dict`, Perl to a hash, etc. The similarity in syntax between Python dict displays and JSON objects confuses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `agents_json` is not an object but a string, with its zeroth element being the bracket, which is printed. You need to work with object, not string representation of json to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: string is a object, as well as a dict or list.

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel Different use of the word "object". "Object" is the official name of the JSON value that represents a mapping, independent of the term "object" in Python that describes instances of a class.